# How to add elastic ip name in AWS via Boto3 API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, elastic-ip

When creating the elastic IP in AWS via [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.allocate_address). API does not give an option to add Name to the elastic IP but this field is available via UI. How can I add Name to elastic IP while creating it or after?

[image]

Following code work:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
addr = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
print addr['PublicIp']
```

But, if I add "name" field, it throws this error:

> ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Unknown parameter in input: "Name", must be one of: DryRun, Domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see there is a tag. It doesn't appear that Elastic IPs support "Tag-On-Create", so you have to create the tag after the EIP has been created.

Try the following:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
addr = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
print(addr['PublicIp'])

response = client.create_tags(
    Resources=[
        addr['AllocationId'],
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'production',
        },
    ],
)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally in AWS, there are no `Name` properties. What you're looking at there in the AWS console is actually a tag whose key is `Name`. Almost all AWS objects can have `Name` tags.

With boto3, you can use the [create_tags()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags) method to set one or more tags. For example:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.create_tags(
    Resources=[
        'eipalloc-12344567890'
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'prod-eip'
        }
    ]
)
```